# Binary Exploitation - How to set GID of a SUID binary using shellcode?

Tags: linux, buffer-overflow, assembly, binary-code

I have a binary that is SUID which I can currently use a buffer overflow exploit to obtain an elevated EUID shell.

However I haven't worked much with changing IDs through shellcode, and the file I need to access requires me to have a GID equal to the EUID I have obtained. However, after obtaining my shell, my GID stays the same as previously.

My question: What system calls or shellcode do I need to execute to elevate my GID to be equal to my EUID when the shell is spawned?

Also: So far I have tried setregid and setegid system calls in shellcode before spawning the shell, however both return "-1" when using a GID that is not already my unprivileged GID.

Thank you.

Comment: Is it suid root?

Comment: No, it is suid another non-privileged user. I did some more research and I'm not sure it's even possible to change GID without a root account..

Comment: That is correct. I posted an answer to that effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [`setgid(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setgid.2.html), the syscall will fail unless the calling process is privileged:

> ```
>    EPERM  The calling process is not privileged (does not have the
>           CAP_SETGID capability), and gid does not match the real group
>           ID or saved set-group-ID of the calling process.
> ```

Unless you are running with the correct [capabilities](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) (specifically `CAP_SETGID`, provided by root), you cannot change your GID to a value which is not your real or saved GID. This limitation applies to any syscall that changes the GID. The manual page on [`credentials(7)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html) is extremely helpful.

You can actually [see where this is done](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16/source/kernel/sys.c#L400) in the kernel:

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE1(setgid, gid_t, gid)
{
    struct user_namespace *ns = current_user_ns();
    const struct cred *old;
    struct cred *new;
    int retval;
    kgid_t kgid;

    kgid = make_kgid(ns, gid);
    if (!gid_valid(kgid))
        return -EINVAL;

    new = prepare_creds();
    if (!new)
        return -ENOMEM;
    old = current_cred();

    retval = -EPERM;
    if (ns_capable(old->user_ns, CAP_SETGID))
        new->gid = new->egid = new->sgid = new->fsgid = kgid;
    else if (gid_eq(kgid, old->gid) || gid_eq(kgid, old->sgid))
        new->egid = new->fsgid = kgid;
    else
        goto error;

    return commit_creds(new);

error:
    abort_creds(new);
    return retval;
}
```